# Fix mysql error: Illegal argument to a regular expression in MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, regex

After the upgrade to MySQL 8.0 I get errors like

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): Unable to save result set in .../dbo_mysql.php on line 127
Datenbankfehler dbo_mysql.php/Zeile 146: select * from test where test REGEXP '[[:<:]]Acetylsalicylsäure[[:>:]]'
Illegal argument to a regular expression.
```

According to [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html), "MySQL 8.0 now implements regular expression support using International Components for Unicode (ICU)."

According to [MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html), "MySQL used Henry Spencer's implementation of regular expressions."

Therefore, since you are using MySQL 8.0, rather than using `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`, you now have to use `\b` instead.

I have a server running with lots of old customers' projects, where it is too much work to update all the code.

How do I get back the old REGEX behaviour in Mysql 8.0?
Maybe is there a config value for the `SQL_MODE`?

Comment: when I reported [bug 95347](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95347) it seems compatibility wasn't a driving requirement. Not sure if [query rewrite](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rewriter-query-rewrite-plugin-usage.html) can help.

Comment: Query rewrite may not help if your regular expressions are in stored routines, or passed as query parameters or even based on strings read from the database itself.

Comment: I don't know if a real workaround. It's annoying that MySQL 8.0 has decided to break backward compatibility more freely than past releases. The regular expression syntax is only one example. I don't know of a solution besides biting the bullet and doing a code cleanup on your projects, and plenty of testing.

Comment: FWIW, there is not any SQL_MODE solution. The regexp parser is delegated to a third-party implementation, so only the old regexp library or the new regexp library is present. There's no way to switch between the two implementations in the same server instance.

Comment: That is a pity, A rework of the code really is not possible in my case. Those are customers` projects. Maybe a global replace `[[:>:]]` with `\b` with `sed 's/\[\[:[<>]:\]\]/\\b/g'` over all folders?

Comment: Then downgrade back to MySQL 5.7? But that just kicks the can down the road. Someday MySQL 5.7 will reach end-of-life. In fact, [the date for 5.7 eol is 2023-10-21](https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/mysql).